# How to install libssl-dev for Strawberry Perl on Windows

Tags: perl, padre

I need to install `Crypt::OpenSSL::PBKDF2`, however it requires libssl-dev, which I don't know how to install on Windows 7. I'm running Strawberry Perl because ActivePerl doesn't have PBKDF2 available.

Comment: ppm is only for ActivePerl. cpan for Strawberry Perl doesn't install libssl-dev libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is explained here: [PerlMonks: How to install libssl-dev for Strawberry Perl on Windows](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1147987)